# Restrict access to cosmos db and app service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cosmosdb, azure-api-management, azure-virtual-network

I have a java app deployed to Azure App Services which uses CosmosDB for storing the application data. Java app in App service is consumed via API management.

I am using P1V3 app service instance, consumption based API management instance and serverless cosmos DB.

I want to add some restrictions to the access of app service and cosmos db.

1. I want to make sure that app service is consumed via the api management only. No direct traffic to app service is allowed.
2. Cosmos DB can be only consumed via the app service which I have deployed.

I need some guidance in this as I am not good in networking security.

Comment: It depends. There's various ways to achieve it but as example; for the connection between app and APIM you could add a client certificate through APIM that is checked on your backend. As for network you can't do a whole lot since the IP of the consumption APIM isn't static. For CosmosDB you could create a private endpoint and have your app setup in a vnet. Then just allow traffic from your app to that endpoint and no other network connections should have access.

Comment: This forum is not really a great place to design and test your application's security defenses. For Cosmos I can suggest using Private Endpoints to only allow App Service to access your Cosmos endpoints via private subnet. Could probably suggest the same between your APIM endpoints and AppService.   Doc on Cosmos DB private endpoints, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-configure-private-endpoints

Answer (score 0):

- Supporting the suggestions of [Mark-Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/884931/mark-brown) and [404](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9034195/404). Even I would suggest private endpoints would be the best part in your case.
- You can set private endpoints for both Azure APIM as well as cosmos db. But as of now, APIM private endpoint is in preview mode.
- Here are the links for creating a private endpoint for [Cosmos db](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-configure-private-endpoints) and [APIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/private-endpoint).

Comment: Since I am using APIM consumption mode, so it doesn`t support private endpoint. I have created the private endpoint for cosmos db but I am getting error while connecting to cosmos db from app service. Query failed with error code 13 and error message 'Error=13, Details='Request originated from IP  through public internet. This is blocked by your Cosmos DB account firewall settings.